# Enumerate all file type associations

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to list all the file type associations app names. My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")

int main()
{
    IQueryAssociations *iQueryAssoc = nullptr;
    HRESULT assocHRes = AssocCreate(CLSID_QueryAssociations, IID_IQueryAssociations, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&iQueryAssoc));

    if (assocHRes == S_OK) {
        HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        LPCWSTR pszAssoc = L".xls";
        HRESULT initAssocHRes = iQueryAssoc->Init(NULL, pszAssoc, NULL, hWnd);

        if (initAssocHRes == S_OK) {
            TCHAR buffer[1024];
            DWORD bufferSize = 1024;
            HRESULT getStrAssocHRes = iQueryAssoc->GetString(ASSOCF_NONE, ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYAPPNAME, NULL, buffer, &bufferSize);

            if (getStrAssocHRes == S_OK) {
                std::wcout << "App name: " << std::wstring(buffer).c_str() << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::wcout << "iQueryAssoc GetString failed!" << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::wcout << "iQueryAssoc Init failed!" << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        std::wcout << "AssocCreate failed!" << std::endl;
    }

    iQueryAssoc->Release();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

My code works but it displays app name only for the ".xls" extension. I think, I need to use the `while (iQueryAssoc->QueryInterface())` to get all of them. Is there any example how to use it? Should I call `init` method first and then `QueryInterface` method or just call `QueryInterface` method without `init` method?

Additionally, I have found the `SHAssocEnumHandlers` method:

```
IEnumAssocHandlers *pEnumHandlers = nullptr;
IAssocHandler *assocHandler = nullptr;
HRESULT initAssocHRes = SHAssocEnumHandlers(NULL, ASSOC_FILTER_NONE, &pEnumHandlers);

if (initAssocHRes == S_OK) {
    while (pEnumHandlers->Next(1, &assocHandler, nullptr) == S_OK) {
        std::cout << "Test..." << std::endl;
    }
} else {
    std::cout << "Failed: " << initAssocHRes << std::endl;
}
```

But for me, it fails with the following error: `Failed: -2147024882 E_OUTOFMEMORY - Failed to allocate necessary memory`. I think, the issue with: `IEnumAssocHandlers` are null and not initialized. What method should I use to initialize the `IEnumAssocHandlers`? Thank you.

I have found, these lines of code leads to `E_OUTOFMEMORY` issue:

```
IEnumAssocHandlers *pEnumHandlers = NULL;
HRESULT initAssocHRes = SHAssocEnumHandlers(NULL, ASSOC_FILTER_RECOMMENDED, &pEnumHandlers);
```

Also, I got this warning:
[image: SHAssocEnumHandlers warning]

Any ideas? Thank you.

**Updated code:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "hresinfo.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")

int main()
{
    IEnumAssocHandlers *pEnumHandlers = nullptr;
    HRESULT initAssocHRes = SHAssocEnumHandlers(NULL, ASSOC_FILTER_NONE, reinterpret_cast<IEnumAssocHandlers**>(&pEnumHandlers));

    if (initAssocHRes == S_OK) {
        IAssocHandler *pAssocHandler = nullptr;
        LPWSTR pszName = nullptr;

        while (pEnumHandlers->Next(1, &pAssocHandler, NULL) == S_OK) {
            if (pAssocHandler) {
                pAssocHandler->GetUIName(&pszName);
                printf_s("%S \n", pszName);
            }
        }

        if (pAssocHandler) {
            pAssocHandler->Release();
        }
    } else {
        HRESInfo::getErrorMsg(initAssocHRes);
    }

    if (pEnumHandlers) {
        pEnumHandlers->Release();
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: AssocCreate(ForClasses) gives/defines a list of element/classes for a given file association. It won't give you the list of possible file associations, if that's why you want.

Comment: @SimonMourier

Yes, I know, but I tried different ways to find the solution.

Comment: You don't seem to know since you show code calling these.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, you are right. I do not know why `SHAssocEnumHandlers` does not work and leads to this issue:
`Warning C6387 '_Param_(1)' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'SHAssocEnumHandlers'.` That is why I am here to find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Hunter91151 It is not clear whether `_Param_(1)` is referring to a 0-based or 1-based parameter number. If 0-based, then it is referring to the `afFilter` parameter, which is not NULL in yr example. If 1-based, then it is referring to the `pszExtra` parameter, which is NULL in your example, but by documentation is *allowed* to be NULL. So such a warning makes no sense either way.

Comment: @Hunter91151 Also, the `reintepret_cast` on `SHAssocEnumHandlers()` is not needed, and the call to `pAssocHandler->Release()` needs to be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Doc is bogus. SHAssocEnumHandlers is hardcoded to return E_OUTOFMEMORY when the first parameter is NULL. You can enumerate HKCR key names (with ASSOC_FILTER_RECOMMENDED) and use them as the first parameter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau

You are right. I tried different options, that is why I added the `reinterpret_cast`. But it does not needed, so I will remove it.

Comment: @SimonMourier

So, what should I put as the first parameter? Thank you.

Comment: Any HKCR key name (like ".xls"). You can enumerate HKCR using registry API: RegEnumKey, etc...

Comment: @SimonMourier

Yes, but I need to find where those extensions are in the registry (keys). Anyway, thank you for the help.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
One more question. Regarding memory management. You said: `the call to pAssocHandler->Release() needs to be inside the while loop`. But in my case I have only one `IAssocHandler *pAssocHandler` object and delete it when the loop exits. So, you mean these overridden memory blocks in the loop are leaked and only the last one is freed? Thank you.

Comment: @Hunter91151 file extensions are subkeys directly underneath `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` that begin with a `'.'` character, ie `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xls`.  Use `RegEnumKeyEx()` to find them, see [Enumerating Registry Subkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/enumerating-registry-subkeys).

Comment: @Hunter91151 yes, that is exactly what happens. You have 1 *variable*, but you are enumerating through (potentially) multiple *objects* using that variable. `Next()` overwrites the variable with a new value each time. So, when enumerating interface objects, each *successful* call to `Next()` needs a `Release()` for every object that `Next()` outputs, before you call `Next()` again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau

Ok. So, this is special for `Next()` function only? Regarding extension, I will manage it. Thank you.

Comment: @Hunter91151 No, it is not special to just `Next()`, this is how COM works in general. [COM memory management rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/managing-memory-allocation) dictate that if a function allocates new memory for output, the caller must free that memory. And if a function returns an interface, the interface's reference count must be incremented upon exit, and the caller must decrement the reference count when done using it. See [Rules for Managing Reference Counts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/rules-for-managing-reference-counts).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which call is actually failing (so please do so), but if you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ienumassochandlers-next) for `IEnumAssocHandlers::Next`, it doesn't say anywhere that the third parameter (`pceltFetched`) can be `nullptr`, so I would change your code to:

```
if (initAssocHRes == S_OK) {
    ULONG handlers_retrieved = 0;
    while (pEnumHandlers->Next(1, &assocHandler, &handlers_retrieved) == S_OK) {
        ...
```

Comment: I have tried your example, but it still the same issue. I have updated the main question. Please, check it out. Thank you.

Comment: Be sure to call `assocHandler->Release()` on each `IAssocHandler` that is returned by `pEnumHandlers->Next()`, otherwise they will be leaked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The code crashes before the `pEnumHandlers->Next()` statement. For some reason, `pEnumHandlers` is NULL. Even when I set it to `SHAssocEnumHandlers` method. From MS docs: `When this method returns, contains the address of a pointer to an IEnumAssocHandlers object.` But in my case it contains NULL, not the address.

Comment: @PaulSanders the `IEnumAssocHandlers::Next()` doc may not mention it explicitly, but by convention most COM enumeration interfaces allow a `fetched` parameter to be NULL when the `celt` parameter is 1, since the return value tells you whether the item was actually fetched or not.

Comment: @Hunter91151 it is not possible for `SHAssocEnumHandlers()` to output a null `IEnumAssocHandlers*` pointer if the return value is `S_OK`. Something else is going on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
But `SHAssocEnumHandlers` method does not return `S_OK`. It fails.

Comment: @Hunter91151 Well, then why are you trying to access the methods of the `IEnumAssocHandlers` at all when `SHAssocEnumHandlers()` tells you that it did not output a valid `IEnumAssocHandlers*` pointer? You won't crash if you don't access an invalid `IEnumAssocHandlers` object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau

As I said early, I tried different options. For example: `HRESULT initAssocHRes = SHAssocEnumHandlers(PCWSTR(L""), ASSOC_FILTER_NONE, &pEnumHandlers);`
Result:
https://i.ibb.co/fSCVWYb/2020-11-23-212625.png

Answer (score 0):

Also first parameter to SHAssocEnumHandlers must not be null:

```
wchar_t *extension = L".jpg";
HRESULT initAssocHRes = SHAssocEnumHandlers(extension, ...
```